# Conflicto con las ramas de git en visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio, git, ramas-git

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto utilizando git hub para el control de versiones. Tengo una rama llamada main y cree una rama llamada pruebas con el comando `git checkout -b pruebas`, hasta ese punto me trae el código que tengo en la rama main, verifico con el comando `git branch` si me encuentro en la rama pruebas y empiezo a realizar los cambios respectivos, pero al cambiar a la rama main me aparece el código que he escrito en la rama pruebas sin haber hecho commit o un `git merge`. Estoy utilizando visual studio code y los comandos los ejecuto desde la consola de git bash. Pero, no sé cómo resolver ese problema o si hay algún paso que no estoy realizando. Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hay ningún problema. Lo que estás viendo es como git se espera que trabaje. Mientras esos cambios estén *flotando* en tu árbol de trabajo (o sea, no sean acometidos), si tú le pides a git que te lleve a otra rama, dichos cambios te van a acompañar. Por eso cuando te vas a `main`, ves que los cambios están ahí... y si te devuelves a la otra rama, se van contigo de nuevo.

Cuando haces checkout con cambios no acometidos, git hace una verificación para saber si es posible dicho checkout. Los archivos que estén modificados con respecto a la rama actual deben ser iguales en la rama a la que quieres ir (o sea, esos archivos deben ser iguales entre `HEAD` y la rama destino). Si ese no es el caso, entonces git lanza una advertencia y el checkout se aborta.... a menos que hagas `checkout -f` y en ese caso los cambios que hiciste **se pierden**.

Si quieres irte a otra rama *sin* llevarte dichos cambios *y* sin perderlos, debes usar *"la caleta"* (o sea, el **stash**):

```
git stash save "ya vuelvo"
# el árbol de trabajo queda limpio
git checkout blahblahblah
# haces lo que necesites aquí
.
.
.
# y ahora te quieres devolver
git checkout -
git stash pop # y volvemos a poner lo que teníamos en el aire
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta y explicación me queda más claro. Sin embargo, investigaré más sobre el tema ya que al parecer es desconocimiento en el manejo de ramas.